# How do I access a helper in an engine from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, rails-console

How do I call a helper inside an engine from the Rails console? I tried

```
app.coverart
app.refinery.coverart
helper.coverart
helper.refinery.coverart
Refinery::Books::Engine.helpers.coverart
Refinery::Books::Engine.app.coverart
Refinery::Books::Engine.app.helper.coverart
```

They all say `NoMethodError: undefined method`.

Rails version 3.2.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include functions from `Refinery::Books::ApplicationHelper` you can do this like the following.

```
irb(main):001:0> include Refinery::Books::ApplicationHelper
irb(main):002:0> respond_to? :function_from_engine_helper
=> true
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to use `include Refinery::Books::BooksHelper`. Foiled by `asset_path` in the method though!

Comment: Not exactly understand what do you mean, but if you need `asset_path` helper in the console, you can't include this, but you can delegate like this: `def asset_path(*args);ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(*args);end`